# How to compose OrderCancelRequest in QuickFix/J

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am trying to create OrderCancelRequest using FIX.4.2 but confused with OrderID,OrigClOrdID and ClOrdID. I searched on the web but it was not clear to me. Please explain those parameters and provide snippet of code for OrderCancelRequest if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you connecting to an external FIX server, like a broker or something?

Comment: I'm connecting to FixImulator QuickFix/J

Comment: That was a vital detail you should have included in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wish to cancel an order you created with `quickfix.fix42.NewOrderSingle`. To send that message you had to assign it a unique `quickfix.field.ClOrdID`. For instance:

```
String instructionId = createNewInstructionId( ); 
quickfix.Message fixMessage = new quickfix.fix42.NewOrderSingle (
    new ClOrdID( instructionId ),
    new HandlInst( HandlInst.AUTOMATED_EXECUTION_ORDER_PUBLIC ), 
    new Symbol( symbol ),
    new Side( Side.BUY ),
    new TransactTime( ),
    new OrdType( OrdType.LIMIT )
);
// ...
```

You need to store this `instructionId` for referencing in further messaging.

If the counterparty accepts the instruction, it does so with an `EXECUTION_REPORT` message (`OrdStatus.NEW`). This execution report will contain an `quickfix.Field.OrderID` field, which is a unique identifier for the order as assigned by the broker (uniqueness within single trading day, or uniqueness across days for multi-day orders). Store this `OrderID` for use in later instructions (`orderIdBroker`).

If you wish to cancel the order, you need to reference the instruction that created the order. The `OrigClOrdID` in this instance is the `ClOrdID` of the `NewOrderSingle` instruction that created the order. The `ClOrdID` field is a unique identifier for the cancel request (a new identifier you assign to the cancel request). If you wish (or the broker requires it) you can supply the `OrderID` you received from the broker:

```
String orderInstructionId = getOrderInstructionId( );
String cancelInstructionId = createNewInstructionId( ); 
quickfix.Message fixMessage = new quickfix.fix42.OrderCancelRequest (
    new OrigClOrdID( orderInstructionId ),
    new ClOrdID( cancelInstructionId ),
    new Symbol( symbol ),
    new Side( Side.BUY ),
    new TransactTime( )
);
// If required, set the OrderID as assigned by the broker:
String orderIdBroker = getOrderIdBroker( );
fixMessage.setField( new OrderID( orderIdBroker ) );
```

Comment: On fxcm, fixMessage.set(account) is needed, too.

Comment: @lamrongol I suppose most counterparties will require an `Account` be specified, even though the FIX standard has this as an optional field.

Answer (score -1):

ClOrdId is the id of the cancel order message you're going to send.
OrigClOrdId is the id of the order message you already sent.
OrderID is the internal id of the order (which may or may not mean anything to the receiver).

How you construct the cancel order depends on who you're sending it to. Here's some code:

```
QuoteCancel qc = new QuoteCancel();
qc.setField(new StringField(131, "RFQ123"));
qc.setField(new QuoteCancelType(1));
```

Have a look at [Fiximate QuoteCancel](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/en/FIX.4.2/body_515190.html) for more. Here's the [Fiximate](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/) front page.